# Could Vue.js router-view name be changed?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I am new to Vue.js and I know there is more than one component in a route with different names.

In App.vue file, could `<router-view name="default">` be changed to other name? Thank you for your help.

**HelloWorld.vue**

```
<template>
  <div class="hello">
    <h1>{{ msg }}</h1>
    <h2>Essential Links</h2>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloWorld',
  data () {
    return {
      msg: 'Welcome to Your Vue.js App'
    }
  }
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
h1, h2 {
  font-weight: normal;
}
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
}
li {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 10px;
}
a {
  color: #42b983;
}
</style>
```

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <!-- <img src="./assets/logo.png"> -->
    <router-view name="default"></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App'
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: 'Avenir', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  text-align: center;
  color: #2c3e50;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
</style>
```

**index.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld'

Vue.use(Router)

export default new Router({
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'HelloWorld',
      component: HelloWorld
    }
  ]
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need [dynamic](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) components for this,

Html code

```
<template>
   <div id="app"> 
    <router-view :is="currentComponent"></router-view>
   </div>
 </template>
```

Js code: here depending on `isTrue` value set whichever component you need.

```
<script>
export default {
  name: 'App' ,
  components: { 
   LoginComponent,
   HelloComponent
   },
   computed: { 
   currentComponent () { 
    return isTrue ? 'HelloComponent' :  'LoginComponent'
     }
    }

}
  </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. But if I just want to change the router-view name statically. Is there any suggestion to do it?

Comment: I wish I could, but router-view does not support name tag change  https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/issues/804&hl=en-IN